# Is every finite spectrum $X$ $K(h)$-locally equivalent to a finite spectrum $Y$ with $\dim (K(h)_\ast Y) = \dim ((H\mathbb F_p)_\ast Y)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, chromatic-homotopy

Let $X$ be a finite spectrum and $K = K(h)$ be the $h$th Morava $K$-theory at the prime $p$. Then $\dim_{K_\ast} K_\ast X$ is [increasing in $h$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429778/is-operatornamedim-kh-ast-kh-ast-x-increasing-in-h), and eventually constant at $\dim H_\ast(X,\mathbb F_p)$.

**Question:** Let $X$ be a finite spectrum. Does there exists a finite spectrum $Y$ which is $K(h)$-locally equivalent to $X$ such that $\dim_{K_\ast}K_\ast Y = \dim_{\mathbb F_p} H_\ast(Y;\mathbb F_p)$?

I think the answer is probably *no*. One way this could be so comes when $\dim_{K_\ast} K_\ast X = 1$ : if there is a nontrivial element of $\operatorname{Pic}(\operatorname{Sp}_{K(h)})$ which is the localization of a finite spectrum, then the answer is *no*. But I'm not sure if such elements exist.

Comment: There is such an element when $n =1,p = 2$: the exotic element in the Picard group (that generates a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in the Picard group) is the $K(1)$-localization of the dual of the `question mark' complex.